# Can not deploy helm chart in Terraform (Kubernetes cluster unreachable)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-gcp

I am started GKE cluster using Terraform ([link](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/kubernetes/provision-gke-cluster)), Now I am trying to release the helm charts on the cluster, and tried for "Nginx Ingress" helm chart which is as follow:

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
  name       = "ingress"
  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart      = "ingress-nginx"
}
```

Terraform Plan:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # helm_release.ingress will be created
  + resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
      + chart            = "ingress-nginx"
      + disable_webhooks = false
      + force_update     = false
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + metadata         = (known after apply)
      + name             = "ingress"
      + namespace        = "default"
      + recreate_pods    = false
      + repository       = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
      + reuse            = false
      + reuse_values     = false
      + status           = "DEPLOYED"
      + timeout          = 300
      + verify           = false
      + version          = "2.3.0"
      + wait             = true
    }
```

But I am getting an error

```
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get https://35.232.164.12/version?timeout=32s: dial tcp 35.232.164.12:443: i/o timeout

  on helm.tf line 36, in resource "helm_release" "ingress":
  36: resource "helm_release" "ingress" {
```

Comment: How is this error related to deploying multiple Helm charts? The error is saying you don't have network connectivity to the API server.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR, I am new to this terraform and I don't know much about it

Answer (score 1):

Here terraform not able to create a connection with Kubernetes cluster. cluster is unreachable.

Also using terraform also have to first setup tiller then and then helm chart will work.

in terraform, you can use `helm` provider, if are using service account you add existing one or create one if required

```
provider "helm" {
  service_account = "${kubernetes_service_account.helm_account.metadata.0.name}"
  tiller_image = "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:${var.helm_version}"
  #install_tiller = false

  kubernetes {
    host                   = "${google_container_cluster.<name>.endpoint}"
    token                  = "${data.google_client_config.current.access_token}"

    client_certificate     = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.data-dome-cluster.master_auth.0.client_certificate)}"
    client_key             = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.data-dome-cluster.master_auth.0.client_key)}"
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.data-dome-cluster.master_auth.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  }
```

one `helm` started running you can start setting up other releases using helm package manager.

you can also check this answer for more details : [Deploying Helm workloads with Terraform on GKE cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676673/deploying-helm-workloads-with-terraform-on-gke-cluster)

Comment: This is for Helm2, I am looking for Helm3

Comment: @RavindraGupta Added an example with Helm3

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with Helm3:

Note:

- `[cluster endpoint]` and `[ca certificate]` are outputs of the cluster that was created with Terraform
- You will need a `cluster.admin` and `iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` roles on the service account

```
    data "google_service_account_access_token" "kubernetes_sa" {
      target_service_account = ""
      scopes                 = ["userinfo-email", "cloud-platform"]
      lifetime               = "3600s"
    }
    
    provider "kubernetes" {
      host  = "https://[cluster endpoint]"
      token = data.google_service_account_access_token.kubernetes_sa.access_token
      cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
        module.gitlab-gke.cluster_ca_certificate
      )
    }
    
    provider "helm" {
      kubernetes {
        host                   = "https://[cluster endpoint]"
        token                  = data.google_service_account_access_token.kubernetes_sa.access_token
    
        cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(
          [ca certificate]
        )
      }
    }
```